# Обязательно ли все свойства биндить?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Интересует: обязательно ли все свойства биндить (например, видимость, `label content`, `IsReadOnly`)  или же можно передавать в `ViewModel` объект Вида через конструктор,  а также какие есть еще обязательные правила или рекомендации при использовании MVVM.

Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А чем плох подход биндить только то, что вам нужно?

Comment: -Не сказал что плох, просто спросил обязательно ли биндить те объекты / свойства, которые меняются и каким-то образом оказывают влияние на UI.

 - Имел ввиду, допускается ли то, что модель вида будет иметь доступ к объектам view.

Comment: @Flash

- Хорошим подходом считается тот, в котором по `XAML` разметке очевидны основные точки соприкосновения `View` и `ViewModel,` а также можно понять, каким образом происходит конвертация данных для их графического представления (то есть каким образом используются объекты с семантикой [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter)).

Comment: - Достичь этого без биндингов обычно можно, но такой подход противоречит концепции `WPF` и скорее применим для `Windows.Forms`.

- Модель в `MVC` и `MVVM` не должна ничего знать про `View.` Как минимум по той причине, что для одной модели можно придумать несколько `View.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такой вопрос у меня обычно возникал, когда я не мог связать логику взаимодействия различных компонентов приложения. У меня было сильное искушение просто добавить объект в ViewModel. Моя рекомендация - детально разработать на листе бумаги иерархию компонентов, продумать хорошо XAML, не лениться писать кажущийся длинный код ViewModel, так как потом он себя окупит меньшими временными затратами на доработку и понимание, так как все будет структурировано. Плюс к этому вы получите хороший опыт разработки распределенных приложений (если оно у вас таковое), навыки создания более "чистого" кода.

Насчет биндинга: Биндить нужно только то, что требует зависимости от данных или логики кода. В большинстве случаев мелкие нюансы убираются лучшим знанием XAML (у него есть набор Trigger, State, Storyboard, Command, element-property->property-element etc). Также если хочется что-то кастомизировать "в комплекте" - есть динамическая загрузка стилей --- Создал макет, прикрепил его к ресурсам (через Key), потом если что загрузил новый словарь ресурсов и все значения стилей, кистей и т.п. См. шаблон `Visual Studio` - `CustomControl`.

Насчет связи компонентов: в WPF (как и в C#) есть очень удобная вещь - Prism. Всю ее можно и не знать сразу, но вот к примеру EventAggregator очень даже полезен при связи компонентов. Если у вас разные компоненты, которые не знают друг о друге ничего, то он вам очень поможет. Также для общего представления о связывании я почитал бы на MSDN про </code>**`MEF`**</code>.